# How to use the scoreboard command in Minecraft 1.8.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to give a score to an arrow as it hits the ground, so I can have a lightning bolt hit it when it hits the ground.

How does one use the scoreboard command? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so first create a quick clock, however you like.
next attach a command block onto the clock and within said command block type the command:
`/scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,c=-1] Arrow 1 {inGround:1b}`.

Place a comparator coming out of it, and into another command block. In that command block type the command:`execute @e[score_Arrow_min=1,type=Arrow,c=-1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~`.

Place a repeater coming out of that command block then finally one more command block after that, with the command:`/kill @e[type=Arrow,score_Arrow_min=1,c=-1]`.

It should look something like this:
Clock > Command Block > Comparator > Command Block > Repeater > Command Block.